# How to select both count and another value from two different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle I have a table called classes which lists out the classes of ships and another table called ships which lists out the names of the ships for these classes. Now I need to find out for each class that has at least 3 ships, how many times has the ships of those classes sunk. To do that I have an outcomes tables which tells me the ship name as well as the result. To do this I've first created a view:

```
CREATE VIEW classes_with_3_ships AS
    SELECT c.class
    FROM Classes c FULL OUTER JOIN Ships s ON s.class = c.class
    GROUP BY c.class
    Having COUNT(s.class) >= 3;
```

And this lists out all the classes that have at least 3 ships. Now I'm trying to use this view to count the amount of times the result in outcomes has been 'sunk'.

```
SELECT c.class, Count(result)
FROM Outcomes o, classes_with_3_ships c
WHERE o.RESULT = 'sunk';
```

And this doesn't work because apparently you can't select both c.class and the count. So how can I make this work?

Some sample data
For Classes

```
Insert Into Classes Values ('Renown','bc','Gt. Britain',6,15,32000);

Insert Into Classes Values ('Kongo','bc','Japan',8,14,32000);

Insert Into Classes Values ('Revenge','bb','Gt. Britain',8,15,29000);
```

For Ships:

```
Insert Into Ships Values ('Haruna','Kongo',1915);

Insert Into Ships Values ('Hiei','Kongo',1914);

Insert Into Ships Values ('Kongo','Kongo',1913);

Insert Into Ships Values ('Ramilles','Revenge',1917);

Insert Into Ships Values ('Resolution','Revenge',1916);

Insert Into Ships Values ('Revenge','Revenge',1916);

Insert Into Ships Values ('Royal Oak','Revenge',1916);
```

So the result of the view should be

```
Revenge
Kongo
```

And the result of the query should be

```
Class        sunk_ships
Revenge          0
Kongo            1
```

And here are the tables

```
Create Table Classes (
    class Varchar(40),
    type Char (2),
    country Varchar(15),
    numGuns Int,
    bore Int,
    displacement Int
);
Create Table Ships (
    name Varchar(40),
    class Varchar(40),
    launched Int
);
Create Table Outcomes(
    ship Varchar(40),
    battle Varchar(40),
    result Char(7)
);
```

Comment: do not forget to join the tables on a column, other wise you will get a Cartesian product

Comment: The problem with that is that the view only lists the classes and nothing else while the outcomes table doesn't list the classes. I tried having the view also list out the ship name but I can't seem to do that because of the group by.

Comment: It would probably help if you can post some sample data ( as create table... and insert into ... statements ) with expected output.

Comment: What is the carnality between ships and outcomes? Is it 1:1? Does every ship have 1 and only 1 outcome? Strange schema if so...

Comment: Can you included the create table statements, cos I have no idea of the column names. And do we know a ship has sunk?

Comment: Ok I just added my table creation statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it without the view and use a subquery instead.

Try this query:

```
SELECT
s.class,
SUM(CASE o.result WHEN 'sunk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sunk_ships
FROM ships s
LEFT JOIN classes c ON s.class = c.class
LEFT JOIN outcomes o ON s.name = o.ship
WHERE c.class IN (
    SELECT
    s.class
    FROM ships s
    GROUP BY s.class
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
)
GROUP BY s.class;
```

The inner query finds the classes that have at least 3 ships. This is used to filter the outer query, which joins the three tables together.

The view is not needed.

One thing to be careful of is the case of the word "sunk". If it is always lowercase, that's fine. Otherwise you might want to enclose the o.result in a LOWER function.

Does this give you the result you need?

Comment: That doesn't work. Again, Outcomes doesn't have a class value. It only lists out the ship name and the battle name. I think that could work however my view would have to be modified so that it includes the ship names or something like that.

Comment: How do you join the outcomes table to the ships table? Is it on ship name?

Comment: Yes. The outcomes table has the ships name.

Comment: Great. Does the query above work now (I've updated the join field)?

Comment: Ok I just added my table creation statements that show you what stuff is in all the tables.

Comment: No it doesn't because my view doesn't have a ship name. It only has classes. The reason for this is because of my group by so I can't seem to select more than just the class in my view.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've updated the answer to not use the view and use a subquery instead. Does this work?

Comment: We're close but is it possible to also list out the ships that haven't been sunk once?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that outcomes table has the ship name column and the result this can be used

```
select c.class, count(*)
from   classes c,
    ships   s,
    outcomes o
where c.class = s.class
      and s.name = o.ship(+)
      and c.class in (select class from classes_with_3_ships)
      and o.result ='sunk'
group by c.class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to create a view that includes the ship names, something like the below should get you there.  But including the ship names in this view isn't required.  I'll elaborate below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CLASSES_WITH_3_SHIPS AS
SELECT CLASS_NAME, SHIP_NAME
FROM(
SELECT CLASSES.CLASS AS CLASS_NAME, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CLASSES.CLASS) AS COUNT_SHIPS,
SHIPS.NAME AS SHIP_NAME
FROM CLASSES
INNER JOIN SHIPS
ON CLASSES.CLASS = SHIPS.CLASS)
WHERE COUNT_SHIPS > 2;

SELECT * FROM CLASSES_WITH_3_SHIPS;
CLASS_NAME  SHIP_NAME
Kongo       Kongo
Kongo       Hiei
Kongo       Haruna
Revenge     Revenge
Revenge     Resolution
Revenge     Royal Oak
Revenge     Ramilles
```

But, this isn't actually needed to count the sunk ships for each class.
With the following view, one can still find the counts.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CLASSES_WITH_3_SHIPS AS
SELECT CLASS_NAME FROM (SELECT SHIPS.CLASS AS CLASS_NAME, 
COUNT(*) COUNT_SHIPS 
FROM SHIPS
GROUP BY SHIPS.CLASS) 
WHERE COUNT_SHIPS > 2;

SELECT * FROM CLASSES_WITH_3_SHIPS;
CLASS_NAME
Revenge
Kongo
```

Then, you can execute a query like the below to fetch the counts of sunk ships per class.

Adding some test data to OUTCOMES:

```
INSERT INTO OUTCOMES VALUES('Haruna', NULL, 'scrap');
INSERT INTO OUTCOMES VALUES('Kongo', NULL,'active');
INSERT INTO OUTCOMES VALUES('Heiei', NULL, 'scrap');
INSERT INTO OUTCOMES VALUES('Ramilles', NULL, 'scrap');
INSERT INTO OUTCOMES VALUES('Resolution', NULL,'active');
INSERT INTO OUTCOMES VALUES('Revenge', NULL,'sunk');
INSERT INTO OUTCOMES VALUES('Royal Oak', NULL,'sunk');
```

Then fetching the counts of sunk ships, per class.  If a class has no sunk ships, zero will be returned:

```
SELECT CLASSES_WITH_3_SHIPS.CLASS_NAME, 
COALESCE(SUNK_SHIP.SUNK_COUNT,0) AS SUNK_COUNT
FROM CLASSES_WITH_3_SHIPS
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT SHIPS.CLASS CLASS_NAME, COUNT(*) SUNK_COUNT
FROM SHIPS INNER JOIN OUTCOMES
ON SHIPS.NAME = OUTCOMES.SHIP
WHERE OUTCOMES.RESULT = 'sunk'
GROUP BY SHIPS.CLASS) SUNK_SHIP
ON CLASSES_WITH_3_SHIPS.CLASS_NAME = SUNK_SHIP.CLASS_NAME;
```

Result:

```
CLASS_NAME  SUNK_COUNT
Revenge     2
Kongo       0
```

Hopefully this gets at what you were looking for.